# How to get relative page for every post: /post-1/contact. /post-2/contact

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Let's say I have a post type called `jobs`, and a page called `contact` with a form in it. Now I want the contact page to show on every job url ending with `/contact`. So `job-1/contact`, `job2/contact` etc.

I want the same contact-page to display but with access to the current job id.

Is this possible?

Comment: This may be difficult to achieve, and it's definitely not best practice for SEO, as search engines will see all of these as duplicates. Why do you need to make the contact page look like a child of multiple jobs? Perhaps there is another approach to the underlying reason that could be solved another way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but think about what WebElaine wrote in comment.

You'll need a query variable (e.g. `jobname`) to store the name of `jobs` custom post type.
You also need a rewrite rule that interprets `/jobs/{post-slug}/contact` address as a "contact" page
and keep `{post-slug}` in query variable `jobname`.

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'se354723_query_vars' );
add_action( 'init', 'se354723_rewrite_job_contact' );

function se354723_query_vars( $vars )
{
    $vars[] = "jobname";
    return $vars;
}
function se354723_rewrite_job_contact()
{
    $cpt_slug    = 'jobs';
    $target_page = 'contact-page-slug';
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "$cpt_slug/([^/]+)/contact/?$",
        'index.php?pagename='. $target_page .'&post_type=page&jobname=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );    
}
```

You can check value of the new query variable (`jobname`) on the "contact" page 
with the [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) function.

```
$jobID = 0;
$jobname = get_query_var('jobname', false);
if ( !empty($jobname) )
{
    $jobname = sanitize_title_for_query( $jobname );
    $arg = [
        'post_type' => 'jobs',
        'name'      => $jobname,
        'fields'    => 'ids',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
    ];
    $result = get_posts( $arg );
    if ( is_array($result) && !empty($result) )
        $jobID = (int)$result[0];
}
```